# How to run a windows command in nsis?

Tags: windows, nsis

I a new in nsis, and i'd like to run a windows command (subinacl) from my nsi file, how can i do it? May be 'exec' somehow?
Thx for the answers

Comment: So i have to execute the cmd and write something in the cmd then start it..

Answer (score 1):

You can modify file/directory/registry ACLs with the [AccessControl plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in).

If you still believe you need to run a external tool you can use `ExecWait '"c:\path\to\app.exe" /param1 "par am 2" /param3'`.

ExecWait will display the console when you run console programs, if you don't want that then you have to use a plugin like nsExec (part of NSIS), [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) or [ExecCmd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in)...

Comment: I think i write it misread (or i dont understand that u write :)) So i have .nsi file where i have to write open cmd in windows and write a command there.

Comment: If you just want to open a console use ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /k' or something like that...

Comment: open console and write in the console line...example cd/user or dir /a or something in the console, so automatically write there

Comment: The ExecDos plugin can write to stdin but you might also be able to just execute `cmd.exe /k mycommand&&mysecondcommand`

Comment: you mean like this one? ExecDos::exec "$sysdir/cmd.exe" "subinacl /grant=User"